# How to store Json in Redis using Java and Query like Elasticserach

Tags: java, redis

I need to insert some Json document in Redis and Query it like Elastic search or MongoDB, How can I implement that in java

Answer (score 1):

Currently the best way to do that is to combine the functionality of [RediSearch](http://redisearch.io) and [ReJSON](http://rejson) using application-side logic. In the near future, these two modules will be integrated.

Disclaimer: ReJSON's author here, my employer is Redis Labs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Spring Data to interact with Redis + I convert POJOs from/into JSON String using Jackson.